# Поиск возможных сумм для конкретного числа в массиве

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Есть некоторый массив чисел:

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 4, 7};
```

Так жесть искомое число: 9

Каким образом можно найти суммы чисел из чисел в массиве? Вот пример результата : `2, 7`, `3, 3, 3`, `5, 4`, `2, 4, 3`. В алгоритмах у меня всё очень плохо и поэтому не знаю даже что загуглить, в какую сторону смотреть?

Comment: Вы знаете что такое рекурсия? Рекурсивные функции писать умеете?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Да, умею. Но к сожалению не могу придумать никакого решения для задачи

Comment: Ну, например, рекурсивно. берем поочередно по числу и смотрим варианты получения нового числа из урезанного множества. Например, выбираем 2. Теперь задача сводится к получению 9-2=7 из множества {3,3,3,5,4,7}.

Comment: @Harry и так до нуля отнимать? Я буду рад если вы запостите решение на любом языке.

Comment: @Harry срезал угол. После выбора двойки надо решить две задачи: "7 из {3,3,3,5,4,7}" и "9 из {3,3,3,5,4,7}"

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Не срезал. Потому что следующим будет найти 6 из {2,3,3,5,4,7}.

Comment: @Harry, я имел в виду что в теле функции должно быть два рекурсивных вызова, вы упомянули только один. Прошу прощения если мой комментарий прозвучал резко. Язык мой - враг мой.

Comment: *Я буду рад если вы запостите решение на любом языке* Могу на С++, но, по-моему, уже после решения @StanislavVolodarskiy, не актуально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот вариант печатает некоторые разложения несколько раз если в массиве несколько одинаковых чисел:

```
using System;

void sums(int[] arr, int target) {
    int[] stack = new int[arr.Length];
    int top = 0;

    void iter(int i, int target) {
        if (target < 0) {
            return;
        }
        if (target == 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < top; ++j) {
                Console.Write(stack[j] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            return;
        }
        if (i < arr.Length) {
            stack[top++] = arr[i];
            iter(i + 1, target - arr[i]);
            --top;
            iter(i + 1, target);
        }
    }

    iter(0, target);
}

sums(new int[] {2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 4, 7}, 9);
```

> ```
> $ csc -nologo temp.cs && mono temp.exe
> 2 3 4 
> 2 3 4 
> 2 3 4 
> 2 7 
> 3 3 3 
> 5 4
> ```

**P.S.** Нет опыта с C#. Возможно, я наделал глупостей.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, работает, я был близко к подобному!  Это уже какой-то существующий алгоритм?

Comment: Это вариант перебора комбинаций всех бит с ранним отсечением. Или это вариант поиска в глубину по дереву битовых комбинаций (тоже с отсечением). В общем это классика.

Comment: И это не самый эффективный алгоритм. Можно улучшить отсечение, можно добавить эвристики, можно убрать дублирование, можно добавить динамику.